# Chrome Extension: how to change JS url before he starts loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, preloading

I wanna change src of js javascript before he starts loading using a Chrome Extension.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"Inject DOM",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
        ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["inject_this.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**inject_this.js**

I execute this code in various functions scenarios

```
var element = event.srcElement;

if(/production_path/.test(element.src)){

element.src = element.src.replace(/production_url/gi, "dev_path");

}
```

**Scenario A**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
```

**Scenario B**

Executing this scenario into inject_this.js throw this TypeError:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined*

Executing this in another js doesn't work

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {

    if(/production_url/.test(details.url)){

       return { 
          redirectUrl: details.usl.replace(/production_url/gi, "dev_url")
       }

    }

},

{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking"]);
```

Where do i put this snippet code ?

**Scenario C**

```
document.addEventListener('beforeload', doBeforeLoad , true);
```

but every time `script.src` is changed too late, the resource is loaded.

How can I change javascript url before he starts loading?

Comment: Scenario B should work, are you using a blocking response?

Comment: Other scenarios will NOT work, but please show more of your code for Scenario B.

Comment: @Xan Done. As i wrote in my edit the code for Scenario B throw a `TypeError` ( *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined* ) if executed inside the injected script. If executed in another js ( included from the injected ) it doesn't trigger . Where do i should inject those snippet of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution B should work.

Two conditions need to be met for this to work:

1. This code should go to a [background script / event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).
2. You need [appropriate permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest): `"webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"`

You probably also should not use it on `<all_urls>`, since your extension seems to be specific to a single site (from your manifest). Doing it on all URLs is going to slow your Chrome down and may lead to breaking other sites, consider using a restrictive match pattern like `"http://www.example.com/*production_url*"`